# Thevenin and Norton Equivalent Question about Current Division

Tags: source, norton

[image]

Hello, I am asked to find the Norton equivalent of this circuit. So I did the calculations with source transformation. I did all the steps right but I am sort of confused on the last step to get the right answer. Initially I used the current division to find the Norton equivalent but it turns out I have already found it by the last source transformation. And I could easily find Rn by using the parallel formula. But I am confused on why I don't have to use current division to find the Norton equivalent in this case?

Comment: I am not 100% sure on what you are asking, so, I'll give it a shot, let me know if I assumed something wrong. But, what if you considered Isc to be a resistor of 0 Ohms?

Comment: @Tyler I am asking why was the current division skipped.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was hinting about. Replace the Isc with a 0 Ohm resistor. Draw the circuit. Look at it…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why I don't have to use current division to find the Norton equivalent in this case?

I'd say the simplest answer is *because you've already found the Norton equivalent*. You just used another technique to arrive at the answer.

A Norton equivalent circuit is just a current source and a shunt (parallel) resistor that has the same response as the original circuit. There are multiple ways to derive this. As you've demonstrated, it is possible to simply apply source transformations and combine resistances to reduce the whole circuit down to just a single current source and a single shunt resistor... which by definition is the Norton equivalent circuit.

It's also possible to analyze the circuit for \$V_{OC}\$ and \$I_{SC}\$ (and then derive \$I_N=I_{SC}\$ and \$R_N = V_{OC}/I_{SC}\$ ) without applying source transformations. If you take that approach, then you would need to perform current division. And you'd end up with the same answer. It's a good exercise to try out.

Comment: In this case since I've already have it parallel with the resistor with the same current thus they both contain the same current. Okay I think I am understanding. Yeah, I think in this case the source transformation was a lot easier than nodal analysis but I should also experiment multiple ways to get a full understanding. Thank you for your explanation.